# Service broker vs normal monitor performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, timer, service-broker

I want to monitor the changes on two tables (in large scale Database ) I have two options

- SqlDependency and server broker
- Normal timer every second to watch

From my  perspective the second choice is not reasonable and headache , I have bad experience with timers

any suggestion regarding the best practice for that

Comment: If all changes to those tables are made by your own application - you can notify about those changes from the application itself.

Comment: @Evk no not by my application I just listen using windows service to the changes to take changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) (aka. SqlDependency) allows you to detect changes *that would modify a query you already run*. They are intended solely for cache invalidation.

To track changes that occur in your tables, even while your client is offline, you need to consider [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) or [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx).

Timers are not an option under any circumstances. They cannot detect changes, they can only run again the same query.

Comment: can u explain more the cache invalidation , I have many apps insert in two tables I have windows service to take action depending on any new insert SqlDependency will help in that right?

Comment: The scenario for which SqlDependency helps is, say, you have an app that display data on a grid. Data is obtained from a DB with a query. As soon as another user modifies a record in the DB, the grid is refreshed to display the new, modified, data.

Comment: If you want a service that needs to *process* something as soon as the an app inserts/modifies data into a table, that is not a SqlDependency scenario. [Use a queue instead](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

Comment: sorry but I want my windows service to get noticed once a change done